# Inserting C-ordinates (LAT. and LONG.) in map composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In QGIS 2.8, how do I insert co-ordinates (degree, minute and second) in map composer?

When I did it, the the X and Y intervals value were showing on the frame instead of actual lat. & long of the area. Intervals unit were set as Map Units. co-ordinate Format as Degree, Minute and second with suffix. But the coordinate appearing on the canvas is not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the print composer you the map has to be selected. Now Go to the Grid section and this is what you normally see:

[image]

Deefine a new grid (plus icon) and in the CRS section choose change. Select the one you want, for instance EPSG 4326. This is what you will have:

[image]

The only thing to do is set the appropriate x and Y interval. Notice that the intervals are set in Map units. In order to show lat lon coordinates you will have to declare the interval in decimal degrees. For instance, lets say you want a lines every 5 minutes. The value for the interval will be 5/60=0.0833333333333333. The value for the interval. Also if you want to show degree, minute, second with suffix do not include decimals for the seconds (Draw coordinates/coordinate precision).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but it is not working.. or may be I am not getting it. Lets take an example of India, its latitude and longitude extent is between 8°4' to 37°6 N and 68°7' and 97°25' E. but i am not getting coordinates like this on my map. What if i want lines every 4 degrees. then what should be my interval units and offset ??

Answer (score 1):

I made a map of India originally in EPSG 4326 and reproject it to Albers India (SR-ORG:8356, spatial reference.org) CRS (+proj=aea +lat_1=28 +lat_2=12 +lat_0=20 +lon_0=78 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=2000000 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs). This CRS is not defined in Qgis so I used the Settings/Custom CRS option in order to define it. The layer and the project are in Albers India.  In the print composer as described before I added a Grid changed the CRS to 4326 (lat lon wgs84) and asked the intervals to be each 4 degrees.

[image]

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gerardo..! problem solved.. this was very useful